# How do I do an AND with jQuery on different attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several DIV tags in a list like this:

```
<div status="1" searchText="some text">...</div>
<div status="2" searchText="more text">...</div>
<div status="1" searchText="even">...</div>
```

I have some buttons to show/hide based on status. The js looks like this:

```
if($(button).attr("active")=="true") {
    $(button).attr("active","false");  // turn off button 
    $('[status="'+status+'"]').hide(200);  // hide divs with status
} else {
    $(button).attr("active","true");  // turn on button
    $('[status="'+status+'"]').show(200);  // show dive with status
}
```

I have a new requrement to filter by searchText.  simple enough, a text form box is set with a keyUp() the js looks like this:

```
var val = elem.value;
$("div[searchText*='"+val+"']").show();
$("div[searchText]:not('div[searchText*=\'"+val+"\']')").hide();
```

The problem is that each one override the other. If I click on the status 1 button, it will show() nomatter what the searchtext is and vice versa.

How do I do an AND on two differnt attribues?  I need something like this:

```
$("div[searchText*='"+val+"']") AND $('[status="'+status+'"]')  then show()
```

Comment: I think you just combine them `$("div[searchText*='"+val+"'][status='"+status+"']")`

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the selector like so:

> > $("div[searchText*='"+val+"'][status='"+status+"']")

Answer (score 0):

What @kei said or you can use filter, e.g:

```
$("div[searchText*='"+val+"']").filter('[status="'+status+'"]')
```